# how to use Entity Recognition with Apache solr and LingPipe or similar tools

Tags: solr, nlp, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I would like to use NLP while indexing the data with Apache Solr.

1. Identify the synonyms of the words and index that also.
2. Identify thenamed entity and label it while indexing.
3. when some one query the Solr Index, I should able to extract the
   named entity and intention from the query and form the query string,
   so that it can effectively search the indexed file.

Is there any tools / plugins available to satisfy my requirements? I believe it is a common use cases for most of the content based websites. How people handling it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [a tutorial on using Stanford NER with SOLR](http://www.searchbox.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-in-solr/).

Comment: url is not available :(

Comment: That site is archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140327221947/http://www.searchbox.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-in-solr/

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Apache UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/)

Specifically, if you need Solr to do named entity recognition, you can integrate it with UIMA using [SolrUIMA](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrUIMA)

Check out this [talk](http://vimeo.com/32406329), that demonstrates UIMA + Solr.