# How to get training dataset of OpenNLP models?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I am using the following models of OpenNLP:

```
en-parser-chunking.bin
en-ner-person.bin
en-ner-location.bin
en-ner-organization.bin
```

I want to append my data in the training dataset on which these models are trained. So please tell me from where I can get that raw dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The section *Chunker Training* of the [official OpenNLP manual](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.7.1/manual/opennlp.html) mentions a reference to the raw data used for the training of the EN language model files:

> The training data can be converted to the OpenNLP chunker training format, that is based on [CoNLL2000](http://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/conll2000/chunking/).

You will also find other references, e.g, *Chapter 12. Corpora*, to external resources used in/for OpenNLP.

Additionally, the CoNLL2003 corpus might be of interest:

> The English data is the Reuters Corpus, which is a collection of news wire articles. The Reuters Corpus can be obtained free of charges from the NIST for research purposes: http://trec.nist.gov/data/reuters/reuters.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please help me for how to train the existing NER models by my own sample data using the openNLP API?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is another question on StOf. I provided you an answer to the question "from where I can get that raw dataset". IMHO it gives a valid and acceptable answer. You might consider asking a new, separate question, and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I have got the reuters dataset but now I just want to know how to proceed with that, appending my own data into it.

Answer (score 0):

there are addons available for that. Use this [modelbuilder-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617540/how-to-update-an-existing-named-entity-recognition-model-rather-than-creatin) to update the existing NER model and also to create a new one in a faster way.

What the code in the link does is read in your sentences, uses the default en-ner-person model to do it's best. Then it writes those results to a file of the good hits, and a file of the bad hits . Then it feeds those files into the "modelbuilder-addon" call at the bottom.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey! is there any examples how to use it to update existing models of OpenNLP?

Comment: checkout my repository : https://github.com/iamgr007/srae/blob/master/src/training/UpdateExisitingModel.java

Comment: hi @iamgr007 ,Thanks will check. But is there maven repo for modelbuilder addon ?

Comment: can you please tell what does getSentencesFromSomewhere() does ? does it brings normal un-annotated sentences to be analyzed for ?
another question, if thats so then how many list of sentence is required in that file so that I can make good model out of it ?

Comment: @AbhishekSengupta getSentencesFromSomewhere() gets the sentences from the dataset you provide, fully annotated (proper pre processing must be done) and I guess there is no limit for no.of sentences as more data = good model. Anyways, try to build a model with a large and extensive dataset. If something doesn't workout, check opennlp documentation for any limitations.