# OpenNLP model builder addon doesnt continue

Tags: java, machine-learning, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm using the `model builder addon` for `OpenNLP` to create a better NER model.
According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617540/how-to-update-an-existing-named-entity-recognition-model-rather-than-creatin), I have used the code posted by [markg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3059517/markg) :

```
public class ModelBuilderAddonUse {

  private static List<String> getSentencesFromSomewhere() throws Exception 
  {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Work\\workspaces\\default\\UpdateModel\\documentrequirements.docx"));
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      {
          list.add(line);
      }
      reader.close();
      return list;

    }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    /**
     * establish a file to put sentences in
     */
    File sentences = new File("D:\\Work\\workspaces\\default\\UpdateModel\\sentences.text");

    /**
     * establish a file to put your NER hits in (the ones you want to keep based
     * on prob)
     */
    File knownEntities = new File("D:\\Work\\workspaces\\default\\UpdateModel\\knownentities.txt");

    /**
     * establish a BLACKLIST file to put your bad NER hits in (also can be based
     * on prob)
     */
    File blacklistedentities = new File("D:\\Work\\workspaces\\default\\UpdateModel\\blentities.txt");

    /**
     * establish a file to write your annotated sentences to
     */
    File annotatedSentences = new File("D:\\Work\\workspaces\\default\\UpdateModel\\annotatedSentences.txt");

    /**
     * establish a file to write your model to
     */
    File theModel = new File("D:\\Work\\workspaces\\default\\UpdateModel\\nl-ner-person.bin");


//------------create a bunch of file writers to write your results and sentences to a file

    FileWriter sentenceWriter = new FileWriter(sentences, true);
    FileWriter blacklistWriter = new FileWriter(blacklistedentities, true);
    FileWriter knownEntityWriter = new FileWriter(knownEntities, true);

//set some thresholds to decide where to write hits, you don't have to use these at all...
    double keeperThresh = .95;
    double blacklistThresh = .7;


    /**
     * Load your model as normal
     */
    TokenNameFinderModel personModel = new TokenNameFinderModel(new File("D:\\Work\\workspaces\\default\\UpdateModel\\nl-ner-person.bin"));
    NameFinderME personFinder = new NameFinderME(personModel);
    /**
     * do your normal NER on the sentences you have
     */
   for (String s : getSentencesFromSomewhere()) {
      sentenceWriter.write(s.trim() + "\n");
      sentenceWriter.flush();

      String[] tokens = s.split(" ");//better to use a tokenizer really
      Span[] find = personFinder.find(tokens);
      double[] probs = personFinder.probs();
      String[] names = Span.spansToStrings(find, tokens);
      for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        //YOU PROBABLY HAVE BETTER HEURISTICS THAN THIS TO MAKE SURE YOU GET GOOD HITS OUT OF THE DEFAULT MODEL
        if (probs[i] > keeperThresh) {
          knownEntityWriter.write(names[i].trim() + "\n");
        }
        if (probs[i] < blacklistThresh) {
          blacklistWriter.write(names[i].trim() + "\n");
        }
      }
      personFinder.clearAdaptiveData();
      blacklistWriter.flush();
      knownEntityWriter.flush();
    }
    //flush and close all the writers
    knownEntityWriter.flush();
    knownEntityWriter.close();
    sentenceWriter.flush();
    sentenceWriter.close();
    blacklistWriter.flush();
    blacklistWriter.close();

    /**
     * THIS IS WHERE THE ADDON IS GOING TO USE THE FILES (AS IS) TO CREATE A NEW MODEL. YOU SHOULD NOT HAVE TO RUN THE FIRST PART AGAIN AFTER THIS RUNS, JUST NOW PLAY WITH THE
     * KNOWN ENTITIES AND BLACKLIST FILES AND RUN THE METHOD BELOW AGAIN UNTIL YOU GET SOME DECENT RESULTS (A DECENT MODEL OUT OF IT).
     */
    DefaultModelBuilderUtil.generateModel(sentences, knownEntities, blacklistedentities, theModel, annotatedSentences, "person", 3);


  }
}
```

It also runs, but my output quits at :

```
    annotated sentences: 1862
    knowns: 58
    Building Model using 1862 annotations
    reading training data...
```

But in the example in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617540/how-to-update-an-existing-named-entity-recognition-model-rather-than-creatin) it should go futher like this :

```
Indexing events using cutoff of 5

    Computing event counts...  done. 561755 events
    Indexing...  done.
Sorting and merging events... done. Reduced 561755 events to 127362.
Done indexing.
Incorporating indexed data for training...  
done.
    Number of Event Tokens: 127362
        Number of Outcomes: 3
      Number of Predicates: 106490
...done.
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem, so I can generate a model?
I have searched realy a lot but cant find any good documutation about it.
Would really appreciat it, thanks.

Comment: Is your compilation terminating?? Looks like it's reading the training data for so long.

Comment: @caffeinator13 Yes it is terminating, it just quits. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the path to your training data file like this:

```
File sentences = new File("D:/Work/workspaces/default/UpdateModel/sentences.text");
```

instead of

```
File sentences = new File("D:\\Work\\workspaces\\default\\UpdateModel\\sentences.text");
```

**Update**

This is how is used, by adding the files to the project folder. Try it like this -

```
File sentences = new File("src/training/resources/CreateModel/sentences.txt");
```

[Check my respository for reference on Github](https://github.com/caffeinator13/srae/blob/master/src/training/CreateModel.java)

This should help.

Comment: This dont work, get the following error : `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Comment: The path is correct now, but the builder still quits at `Building Model using 1358 annotations reading training data...`

Comment: You've 1862 annotated sentences right? Check for any error in the sentence 1358

Comment: I dont know how the `1862` came there, but if I run it it end at `Building Model using 1358 annotations`. When I go to `sentence 1358` its the last line from `annotated sentences` nothing different the the other lines. Any idea?

Comment: it might have something to do with your training set. I guess it's too late for my suggestion @Patrick, I just wanted to know if the issue was resolved! How did it go?