# How to create a simple Italian Model for a Named Entity Extraction of Persons using OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, named-entity-recognition, opennlp

I have to do a project with OpenNLP, strictly in italian language. Since it's almost impossible to find some existing structures in this language, my idea is to create a simple model myself. Reading some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950036/opennlp-model-builder-addon-doesnt-continue) on this platform, my idea is try to do this using [model-builder addon](https://github.com/apache/opennlp-addons/tree/master/modelbuilder-addon).

First of all, it's possible to obtain my goal with this addon?
If so, referring to this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509678/opennlp-foreign-names-does-not-get-recognized/21323571#21323571), what kind of file is meant by "modelOutFile"? In my case I don't have an existing model.
N.B.: the addon uses some deprecated functions (such as `nameFinderME.train()`).

Naively, I tried to pass as a "modelOutFile" a simple empty file "model.bin", but, of course I bumped into an error:

> Cannot invoke "java.util.Properties.getProperty(String)" because "manifest" is null

Furthermore, I used a few names and sentences for the test (I only wanted to know if this worked), not the large amount requested (15000 sentences at least).
I'm open to other suggestions instead of the use of modelbuilder addons.
Hope someone can help me.