# How many lines and documents should be there in the training data opennlp categorizer

Tags: opennlp

I am following the [documentation for `Apache open-nlp`](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html). I was able to understand the sentence detection, tokenizer, name-finder. But I got stuck for Categorizer. The reason, I can not understand, how to create a model for Categorization.

I do understand that I need to create a file. The format is very clear, it needs to be a category space and a document in a single line. Save the file with `.train` extension.

So I created the following file:

```
Refund What is the refund status for my order #342 ?
NewOffers Are there any new offers for your products ?
```

I gave this command-

`opennlp DoccatTrainer -model en-doccat.bin -lang en -data en-doccat.train -encoding UTF-8`

It starts doing something and then returns with an error. These are the contents in the command prompt:

```
Indexing events using cutoff of 5

    Computing event counts...  done. 2 events
    Indexing...  Dropped event Refund:[bow=What, bow=is, bow=the, bow=refund, bow=status, bow=for, bow=my, bow=order, bow=#342, bow=?]
Dropped event NewOffers:[bow=Are, bow=there, bow=any, bow=new, bow=offers, bow=for, bow=your, bow=products, bow=?]
done.
Sorting and merging events... Done indexing.
Incorporating indexed data for training...  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at opennlp.maxent.GISTrainer.trainModel(GISTrainer.java:263)
    at opennlp.maxent.GIS.trainModel(GIS.java:256)
    at opennlp.model.TrainUtil.train(TrainUtil.java:184)
    at opennlp.tools.doccat.DocumentCategorizerME.train(DocumentCategorizerME.java:162)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.doccat.DoccatTrainerTool.run(DoccatTrainerTool.java:61)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.CLI.main(CLI.java:222)
```

I am just not able to figure out why is this giving a null pointer exception here? I also tried to increase two more lines, but no result.

```
Refund What is the refund status for my order #342 ?
NewOffers Are there any new offers for your products ?
Refund Can I place a refund request for electronics ?
NewOffers Is there any new offer on buying worth 5000 ?
```

I found [this blog](http://rimmythepaperclip.blogspot.in/2015/01/using-apache-opennlp-document.html), but here also pretty much the same thing is done. On trying his training file it works with a charm. What is wrong in my file? How do I resolve the error.

When I try `opennlp DoccatTrainer` it opens help for me, so path is not an issue. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: I changed the file to

```
Refund What is the refund status for my order #342 ? Can I place a refund request for clothes ?
NewOffers Are there any new offers for your products ? what are the offers on new products or new offers on old products?
Refund Can I place a refund request for electronics ?
NewOffers Is there any new offer on buying worth 5000 ?
```

and it works, I thought it has got to do something with the document (apparently should be two sentences) and removed the last two lines.

to make it

```
Refund What is the refund status for my order #342 ? Can I place a refund request for clothes ?
NewOffers Are there any new offers for your products ? what are the offers on new products or new offers on old products?
```

But then again it fails, the question now summarizes to what kind of data/ format/document does it need?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to add more than 5 samples from each category. because default cutoff mark size is 5,

Please refer this blog post 
http://madhawagunasekara.blogspot.com/2014/11/nlp-categorizer.html

Comment: It requires 5 samples overall (**not** 5 sample/category).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -cutoff flag in your DoccatTrainer command to change the default. In your case, you would add -cutoff 1 to set the minimum number of documents per category to 1.

Comment: **-cutoff doesn't work** with openNLP's DoccatTrainer