# Custom model creation and traning for openNLP

Tags: nlp, opennlp

My requirement is to analyze sentence like. "Find me The Hungry Tide book." or "The Hungry Tide or Broken Mirror which one is better." where Hungry Tide and Broken Mirror are books name, for this i need to create a custom models to find the books title in given array of tokens. So that later on i can create a query based on given sentence. Please let me know how i can achieve this or if there is any other way to analyze the sentence like that.

Answer (score 0):

http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html

this documentation is very useful. Follow the code examples. Check Name Finder tool and training of Name Finder.

Related Question: 
[How to create Custom model using OpenNLP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963972/how-to-create-custom-model-using-opennlp)